# In RoR, f.fields_for is rendering as nothing

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, parent, fields-for

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  In my model I have

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    …
  belongs_to :address, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :my_object_times
```

and the address model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :country
  ...
  has_one :my_object

end
```

I want to write a form that will allow me to build both the child and parent objects, so I tried

```
<%= form_for @my_object, :url => my_objects_create_path, :remote => true do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :address do |addr| %>
    <%= addr.label :address %> <span name="my_object[address]_errors"></span><br>
    City: <%= addr.text_field :city %>
    <%= addr.select :state, options_for_select(us_states.collect{|s| [ s.name, s.id ]}), {:prompt => "Select State"} %>
    <%= country_code_select('my_object[address]', 'country_id',
              [[ 'US', 'United States' ], [ 'CA', 'Canada' ]],
              {:include_blank=>true, :selected => @default_country_selected.id},
              {:class=>'countryField'}
              ) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

but the above is rendered as only

```
<div class="field">
</div>
```

How do I adjust things so that my fields render AND I'm able to create my object in my controller using

```
my_object = MyObject.new(params)
```

**Edit:** Per the answer given, I tried

```
@my_object.address.build
```

from teh controller action taht rendres the form, but got the erorr

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#this is in form loading class**

```
def new
    @myobject = MyObject.new
    @myobject.address = Address.new
end
```

**#Now you can use nested attribute for Address**

```
<%=form_for(@myobject) do |f|%>
<%=f.fields_for :address do |a|%>
    Your form fields here
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

**#this is create def**

```
def create 
@myobject = MyObject.new(myobject_params)
@myobject.save
end
```

**#in params**

```
def myobject_params
params.require(:myobject).permit(:some, :key,:of, :myobject, :address_attributes[:address, :attribute])
end
```

**#this should work**

Comment: I got the error "undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass" on the line "@myobject.address.new"

Answer (score 1):

If `my_object` has no addresses, then nothing will be rendered.  This is default behavior in Rails.  One way to get around this is to build one or more empty children in the controller so that at least one set of fields is shown to the user

The Rails [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) talk about this in Nested Forms section 9.2

Also, in your MyObject model, i think it should be `has_one address`.  you have `belongs_to`

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Comment: My "my_objects" table has an "address_id" column that links back to the "addresses" table.  Given that, do you still say the relation should be "has_*" instead ob "belongs_to"?

Comment: sorry not knowing what `my_object` refers to, i can't say how you should structure your data assocations.  The reason why `@my_object.address.build` gives that error is because with `has_many` association the builder should be `@my_object.addresses.build`.  Or it could be `has_one`.  Either way with a nested form it makes sense for the child object to `belong_to` the parent object.  I'm not sure if you can make it work the other way - that i don't know honestly

Comment: in any case maybe try to have a blank `address` instance object in your my_object controller in the new action to get the form to render.  See if that helps

Comment: In the Rails documentation -- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, Book belongs_to Author, and as such the "books" table has an "author_id".  My "my_objects" table has a "address_id", so I shoudl also use belongs_to, no?  Also, could you give an example of the code I would use in your other comment to get the field to render?

Comment: yes if `my_object` belongs to `address` then `my_object` will have an `address_id`.  That is true.  But what i'm saying is that your associations aren't making sense if you have address nested inside my_object. when you have my_object `accepts_nested_attributes_for`  address then address should belong_to my_object, not the other way around.  See [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in the Rails docs for examples.

Comment: I think when i suggested `has_many`, that was confusing.  Actually `has_one` makes more sense.  My_object has_one address.  I edited my original answer to reflect this

Comment: If I implement has_one, will I have to change my database structure?

Comment: you would have to generate a migration to add a `my_object_id` column to the `address` table

Comment: I have several tables taht point back to the "addresses" table.  So per your suggestion, I should go and add a column to my addresses table for each table that references it?  Then I would have an address row with "address.user_id," "address.event_id," "address.organization_id," even though only one of those columns would be used?  Sorry, but that seems ridiculous.  I have a hard time believing Rails is so inflexible as to force someone to do this.

Comment: If a model `belongs_to` another model, then yes there should be a reference column.  I don't know what else to tell you..I'm not suggesting to overhaul your entire database schema if you don't have to.  I don't know how you have your data organized or how your app works.  But for your nested form to work, things have to be organized a certain way, that's all.  Your nested object, address, isn't rendered because there are no instances of it for Rails to render.  That's the main issue so focus on that.  Make sure that a nested form is appropriate here too..

Comment: Maybe repost this question with more info and use the "ruby-on-rails" tag so that you get far more viewers?  you only tagged "ruby-on-rails-4".  Good luck

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  What "more info" would you suggest I include?

Comment: definitely include your my_object controller and maybe your address.rb (model)